# Huffman Coding Issue with file size after compression

Tags: c#, huffman-code

I am using Huffman code to create a compression algorithm for compressing any sort of file , but I can see that the compressed size is almost same as the original size. E.g 25 mb video occupies 24 mb after compression and 606 kb image occupies 605 kb after compression. Below is my entire code. Kindly let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

```
     public static class ByteValues
      {
        public static Dictionary<byte, string> ByteDictionary;

        public static void AddValues(byte b, string values)
         {
          if (ByteDictionary == null)
          {
          ByteDictionary = new Dictionary<byte, string>();
           }

      ByteDictionary.Add(b, values);
        }

  public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(this List<T> list, int parts)
  {
      int i = 0;
      var splits = from item in list
                   group item by i++ % parts into part
                   select part.ToList();
      return splits.ToList();
  }
}


    public class Node
    {
    public byte value;
    public long freq;
    public Node LeftNode;
    public Node RightNode;

    public void Traverse(string path)
    {
        if (LeftNode == null)
        {
            ByteValues.AddValues(value, path);
        }
        else
        {

            LeftNode.Traverse(path + "0");
            RightNode.Traverse(path + "1");
        }
    }

}

   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<byte, long> Bytefreq = new Dictionary<byte, long>();
    string filename;
    List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        filename = dialog.FileName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= byte.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                Bytefreq.Add((byte)i, 0);
            }
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
    }


    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filename)))
        {
            long length = reader.BaseStream.Length;
            int pos = 0;
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                pbProgress.Maximum = length;
            });

            while (pos < length)
            {
                byte[] inputbytes = reader.ReadBytes(1000000);
                Bytefreq = inputbytes.OrderBy(x => x).GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (long)(Bytefreq[x.Key] + x.Select(l => l).ToList().Count));
                pos = pos + inputbytes.Length;
                worker.ReportProgress(pos);
            }
        }

    }
    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }



    void worker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("DONE");
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbProgress.Value = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<byte, long> kv in Bytefreq)
        {
            Nodes.Add(new Node() { value = kv.Key, freq = kv.Value });
        }

        while (Nodes.Count > 1)
        {
            Nodes = Nodes.OrderBy(x => x.freq).ThenBy(x => x.value).ToList();
            Node left = Nodes[0];
            Node right = Nodes[1];

            Node newnode = new Node() { LeftNode = left, RightNode = right, freq = left.freq + right.freq };
            Nodes.Remove(left);
            Nodes.Remove(right);
            Nodes.Add(newnode);
        }

        Nodes[0].Traverse(string.Empty);

        BackgroundWorker worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker1.DoWork += worker1_DoWork;
        worker1.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += worker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
    void worker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        Dictionary<byte, string> bytelookup = ByteValues.ByteDictionary;
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Test.txt")))
        {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filename)))
            {
                long length = reader.BaseStream.Length;
                int pos = 0;

                while (pos < length)
                {

                    byte[] inputbytes = reader.ReadBytes(1000000);
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    List<string> outputbytelist = inputbytes.Select(b => bytelookup[b]).ToList();

                    outputbytelist.ForEach(x => builder.Append(x));

                    int numOfBytes = builder.ToString().Length / 8;
                    var bytesAsStrings =  builder.ToString().Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i })
                                                            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 8)
                                                            .Select(g => new string(g.Select(x => x.Char).ToArray()));
                     byte[] finalbytes = bytesAsStrings.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 2)).ToArray();
                     writer.BaseStream.Write(finalbytes, 0, finalbytes.Length);
                    pos = pos + inputbytes.Length;
                    worker.ReportProgress(pos);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'll pass on analyzing your uncommented code, but are you expecting huffman coding to a) compress anything at all, and b) specifically compress video?

Comment: Videos and images typically use huffman or similar codings already, and may not be easily compressible further in a lossless way. Can you get better compression on your samples using e.g. xz or 7z? How much compression did you expect?

Comment: Compressing compressed doesn't compress as good as compressing uncompressed.

Comment: Hi Poldie, I want to make the applicaiton work for all kinds of files , but the must have formats include - JPEG, GIF, PNG, TGA, TIFF MOV, QT, AVI, MPEG-1 –

Comment: Huffman coding is just the first part of writing a compressor (it's sort of a compressor by itself but not a very effective one generally). I think you need to have a bit of a read on exactly what they are for, and how they work, then look at how the data is stored in files of the formats you've just specified, and you'll see how what you're doing is going to increase the size of the files you process, generally, rather than decrease them.  Thought experiment: suppose you compress a file once; what's to stop you compressing it again and again?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the *type* of data you trying to compress. So when you say "E.g 25 mb video occupies 24 mb after compression", the key word here is *video*. Video data is notoriously hard to compress (much like other types of binary data, such as music or images).

If you need to compress video, I'd search for dedicated codecs (MP4, MPEG, H.264), but some may not be free to use so watch for licenses costs. Note, that most codecs are lossy - they try to preserve *visible* quality but remove other information from video. Most of this stuff is good enough, but at some moment you may notice artifacts.

You can also attempt to use lossless compression (like Huffman, gzip, LZ, LZMA, 7z, most available from [7 zip sdk](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) etc), but this won't compress your data well due to it's nature. The basic idea is: the more data resembles random noise, the harder it is to compress. Bonus point: you cannot physically compress random data with *any* lossless compression even by 1 bit ([read about this here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-8.html)).

Comment: Actually I am creating Huffman compressor as a part of my assignment , so I have to do that way only , and the required format that needs to be supported for compression includes  JPEG, GIF, PNG, TGA, TIFF  MOV, QT, AVI, MPEG-1

Comment: It's fine as an assignment, but don't expect it to compress much. If you make and interface for it as `byte[] Compress(byte[] input)` and similar for decomression you can compress *any* data, as at the end of the day everything can be represented as byte[]. The input data you trying to compress is already *highly compressed*, meaning it looks like random data. The closer you get to randomness, the harder it will be to compress and at some point compression meta-data may outweigh compression gains and the output compressed file may become larger (as it contains meta-data + raw compressed byte).